# How to decrement value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
  Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: 5}});
```

I want to drecement the score .

```
 Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: 5}});
```

score 5
score 4

decrement by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment the `score` by -1 will allow decrementing by 1.

```js
Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: -1}});
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f6t6RY_JAIp)

Comment: Yea, its works ✔